# Similarity calculation in a database

Tags: database, set, cluster-analysis, similarity

I have sets each containing a non-constant number of elements. They are represented in a database as shown below (this is a very simplistic example)

I have two problems

1. How to efficiently calculate the similarity?
2. How to represent the calculated similarity in a database?

Note that the current algorithm will not scale well because of the n! complexity.

Note: I can change the representation of the database as well as the algorithm used to calculate the similarity.

[image: Image representing the before and after states of the problem]

Comment: This is an awful database schema for this task. Use inverted lists, as used in e.g. Lucene (text search).

Comment: Thank you. I think you are completely right. How fast will it improve the calculation speed and how do I represent the similarity index in the database? or should I calculate it at fetch time?

Comment: Depends on your sparsity. If the sets are very sparse, the speedup can be drastically. Think of lucene vs. linear scan.

Comment: Thank you :) What about the other question: how should I represent the similarity index in dB or should I calculate it when user fetched the data? Any suggestions?

Comment: Storing all similarities in a database is usually not sensible - too inefficient, and uses O(n^2) memory.